# Problem with temporary folder location in NodeJs Azure Function

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

In my function I'm writing something to a file.
The file path provided by me is d:/local/temp, as suggested in documentation.

The command successed and next in the same function I'm listing the directory content, the file is there.

But when I go via console or Kudu to d:/local/temp, it doesn't contain the content I created. I can confirm it with 'dir filename /s on D drive'

When I run the function again I still can list all previously generated files, so they didn't go

So the d:/local/temp in Kudu/console for the App function and the nodejs code is not the same path, but how I can find the real location of my files?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add an additional option `/B` or `/b` for the command `dir <filename> /S` to show the full path of a file, as below.

```
dir <filename> /S /B
# the result is like D:\<full-parent-path>\filename
```

Fig 1. Sample to find files named `host.json` and show the full path

[image]